# How can i use the same sentence to print several variables without re-writing the sentence?

Tags: python

I have a txt file with numbers in it.

Every couple of numbers is "a case" (ex. `21\n 3\n 45\n 7\n`: `21` and `3` would be one case, `45` and `7` would be another case, and so on).

There are ten cases. I wrote a Python script that could read the txt file and transform the strings in it into integers, which they are.

Now I need to print a sentence with the first number and the second number of every case. I dont want to write ten sentences, is there a way to fix this code

```
file = open('problemCases.txt', 'r')
fileLst = file.readlines()

fileLst = [int(i) for i in fileLst]


def main():
    lst = []
    probCase = (fileLst[0], fileLst[1])
    lst.append(probCase)
    probCase = (fileLst[2], fileLst[3])
    lst.append(probCase)
    probCase = (fileLst[4], fileLst[5])
    lst.append(probCase)
    probCase = (fileLst[6], fileLst[7])
    lst.append(probCase)
    probCase = (fileLst[8], fileLst[9])
    lst.append(probCase)
    probCase = (fileLst[10], fileLst[11])
    lst.append(probCase)
    probCase = (fileLst[12], fileLst[13])
    lst.append(probCase)
    probCase = (fileLst[14], fileLst[15])
    lst.append(probCase)
    probCase = (fileLst[16], fileLst[17])
    lst.append(probCase)
    probCase = (fileLst[18], fileLst[19])
    lst.append(probCase)

    # case 1
    print(
        "If together they have ",
        lst[0][0],
        " shirts, and Dude1 has ",
        lst[0][1],
     " more shirts than Dude2.")
    print("Dude1 has: ", (lst[0][0]-lst[0][1])/2+lst[0][1])
    print("Dude2 has: ", (lst[0][0]-lst[0][1])/2)
```

Comment: http://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops

Answer (score 0):

Loops are great

To built your list, just loop over your input with a step size of 2

```
lst = []
for i in xrange(0, len(fileLst), 2):
    lst.append((fileLst[i], fileLst[i + 1]))
```

EDIT:

As Kevin suggested, We can also take advantage of iterators to avoid annoying (this is python after all) list indexing:

```
for i, j in enumerate(range(1, len(fileLst)+1)): 
    lst.append(fileLst[i], fileLst[j])
```

You can use similar logic for your prints

Comment: Be more Pythonic: `for i, j in enumerate(range(1, len(fileLst)+1)): lst.append(fileLst[i], fileLst[j])`. Also, where does `num` come from?

Comment: Good call, iterators FTW

Comment: Brilliant! That helped a lot believe it or not. Thanks a lot for the fix, now it look better, or at least acceptable lol